# Combobox inside Extjs editor grid panel while populating is invisible sometimes

Tags: extjs, extjs3

Hi all I am using Extjs 3.4 my problem is I have one editor grid panel 
and inside panel I have one department combobox. So, in first page I 
have search grid and on click of grid I am coming to this page and on 
load using ajax I am populating combobox value in grid panel. But sometimes 
values are not coming, means it is invisible and only after clicking on that 
combobox it is appearing. Can some body explain what is the problem.

Thanks in advance, I hope will get reply soon.
  While populating I am calling one ajax which is populating values in grid but 
  there is no issue with other columns, only with combobox it is invisible sometimes

```
    Ext.util.Format.comboRenderer = function(Departmentscombo){

    return function(value){
        var record = combo.findRecord(combo.valueField || combo.displayField, value);
        return record ? record.get(combo.displayField) : combo.valueNotFoundText;
    }
} 

    Ext.grid.ComboColumn = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.Column, {
    constructor: function(cfg){
        Ext.grid.ComboColumn.superclass.constructor.call(this, cfg);
        this.renderer = Ext.util.Format.comboRenderer(this.editor.field ? 
        this.editor.field : this.editor);
        }
     });


    Ext.apply(Ext.grid.Column.types, {
    combocolumn: Ext.grid.ComboColumn
    });

     var DepartmentsJReader = new Ext.data.JsonReader
     ({ root: 'data', id:    'mastercode'      },   
     [{ name: 'mastercode' }, { name:  'description'}]);

        Departments_store = new Ext.data.Store
        ({
            proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy(
                { url: '', method: 'GET' }),
            reader: DepartmentsJReader, autoLoad: true,
            listeners:
            {
                load: function () {
                    var rec = new Departments_store.recordType({ mastercode:'-', description: '-' });
                    rec.commit();
                    Departments_store.insert(0, rec);
                    Departments_store.commitChanges();
                }
            }
        });
```